# org.idempiere.fa.model.ModelValidator nulljava.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, adempiere, idempiere

I am just a newbie on Adempiere. I downloaded the Adempiere's project and run setup. After that, I've got this error and couldn't find the answer on google.

[image]

[image]
Does anyone have any idea about this error.

Answer (score 3):

The error you have is due to custom code been defined in the ModelValidator window of ADempiere where the custom module is not compiled together into the binary. But as Colin Rooney asked for clarification, your error pop up box is specifying 'iDempiere' in some data. I can see it is ADempiere as the project logo is clearly ADempiere's and not to be the newer fork, iDempiere's. Also in your error-stack the log name is ADempiere.
Nevertheless the issue is the same for both. Just go to your database (most likely Postgres) go to the ModelValidator table and the FA module record, uncheck the IsActive field or delete the record. 
To introduce the FA module you have to first compile it together with the whole ADempiere codebase before deploying.
iDempiere is different, as it does not lock modules in its meta data anymore. It is injected purely by OSGi plugin much like how Eclipse IDE works. I have a movie comparing both ways of deploying custom changes: http://youtu.be/Pm0DzUbVhes

Comment: > I can see it is ADempiere as the project logo is clearly ADempiere's
Well spotted Redhuan!

> go to the ModelValidator table and the FA module record, uncheck the IsActive field
This is the right solution ok.
The database table is called ad_modelvalidator so you want to 
UPDATE AD_MODELVALIDATOR SET ISACTIVE='N' WHERE AD_MODELVALIDATOR_ID=...

FYI, I see in my seed db for adempiere 3.80 this record points class org.compiere.FA.model.ModelValidator

Comment: I followed your answer, modified that table. After that I got another new error `the program assumes database version but database has version this is likely to cause hard to fix errors. please stop and migrate the database immediately`

Comment: Which version of Adempiere?  My first thought is, the wrong db seed was loaded! Did you import it after setup using the ADEMPIERE_HOME/util/RUN_ImportAdempiere.sh ?

Answer (score 1):

> I downloaded the Adempiere's project and run setup.

Did you download Adempiere or iDempiere? From the error it looks like iDemiere but that's not what you say.  For support questions like this on Adempiere you'd be better asking for help in their forums or their [gitter room](https://gitter.im/adempiere/adempiere)

Stackoverflow is directed at developers and development/coding issues.

Comment: I did download Adempiere and i have no idea why it appeared idempiere. And thank for the link.